# Migration/Exception : Invalid config filename

Tags: magento2, migration, data-migration-tool

I am migrating Magento 1.9.3.9 to Magento 2.2.5 and getting below error

The command I run from my Windows machine

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.9/config.xml
```

Getting error in command prompt

```
 [Migration\Exception]
 Invalid config filename: vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensourc
 e-to-opensource/1.9.3.9/config.xml
```

**EDIT**

When remove below part it start process but nothing import as all are in comment or removed

```
<steps mode="data">
    <step title="Data Integrity Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
    </step>
    <step title="EAV Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Log Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Ratings Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Tier Price Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="PostProcessing Step">
        <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
    </step>
</steps>
```

**When Comment below part from config.xml it start reading but gives error `Integrity check failed` whats wrong with this part**

```
<step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
```

Comment: By default the file name is config.xml.dist, can you confirm you have changed the filename.

Comment: yes its `config.xml` only

Comment: Can you try making it .dist again and run command with dist. I know it is the same but you can try.

Comment: it work but nothing to migrate.

Comment: You have put the code back which you shared above that you removed, right?

Comment: yes i have reverted back to original config.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80105/discussion-between-zaheerabbas-and-law).

Comment: Congrats that it works now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find answer myself.

I was trying to run a command `php bin/magento migrate:data --reset D:\wamp64\www\mage225no\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensource-to-opensource\1.9.3.9\config.xml` in development mode.

So it every time when run it shows `Invalid config filename`.I research and get some idea about why this happens and finally got the answer that we must run this command in `default` mode don't know about `production` mode.

BTW,Thank you everyone, who help me on this.

Comment: Yes i need to change from developer mode to default mode , for migration to works perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

Please give full path and try:

php bin/magento migrate:data --reset /var/www/html/{{magento2}}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/{{magento1 version}}/config.xml

Comment: not working `php bin/magento migrate:data --reset D:\wamp64\www\mage225no\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensource-to-opensource\1.9.3.9/config.xml`

Comment: try using forward slash:
D:/wamp64/www/mage225no/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.9/config.xml

Comment: already tried that